# Unable to open a local HTML file generated in folium using wxPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets, folium

I am currently trying to plot GPS coordinates as markers on a map and displaying the result within wxPython.

I have used folium to plot coordinate markers and generate an HTML file:

```py
import folium
fmap = folium.Map([-43.5321,172.6362], zoom_start=12)
folium.Marker([-43.5321,172.6362], popup='Marker1').add_to(fmap)
fmap.save('maparea.html')
```

I am able to open this HTML file in Firefox without any issues.

I need to create a programme in wxPython to display this HTML file, and I tried implementing the following code:

```py
import wx 
import wx.html2 

class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds): 
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds) 

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
        self.browser.LoadURL("maparea.html")
        sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10) 

        self.SetSizer(sizer) 
        self.SetSize((1280, 720)) 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  app = wx.App() 
  dialog = MyBrowser(None) 
  dialog.Show() 
  app.MainLoop()
```

However, all I get is a blank page. If I change the URL in the code to a website (e.g. http://www.google.com), the code above works without issues.

Why am I unable to view the HTML file in wxPython? Is there another way to load and display an HTML file in wxPython? I would prefer to use the HTML file over displaying a screenshot in wxPython, since I would like to retain the ability pan, zoom and click on markers within the map.

*(I'm running Python 3.6.8 and wxPython 4.0.3 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the file path needing to be a file:///url there appears to be some issue with an invalid character.
Try it without asking for the `folium.Marker` and you should see a map of Christchurch.

Edit:
folium is using for the `Marker` the wrong character for a single quote `'` it's using ` instead in it's var declarations.
i.e. instead of

```
var html_280344edc4004eb6b0012ec2e57f9b85 = $('<div id="html_280344edc4004eb6b0012ec2e57f9b85" style="width: 100.0%; height: 100.0%;">Marker1</div>')[0];
```

it is providing:

```
var html_280344edc4004eb6b0012ec2e57f9b85 = $(`<div id="html_280344edc4004eb6b0012ec2e57f9b85" style="width: 100.0%; height: 100.0%;">Marker1</div>`)[0];
```

You can replace them or use `webbrowser` rather than `wx.html2`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to convert the file path into a URL first (i.e. `file://path/to/file.html`), you can use `wxFileSystem::FileNameToURL()` function for that.

See https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_file_system.html#a616610cafdb14b841940d5e6b08a9615

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but wxPython still renders an empty page. I changed the path to something that doesn't exist, and wxPython displayed an error message, so the path of my HTML page exists to wxPython. Could my problem be something to do with the fact that the HTML page is trying to load Javascript and CSS code?

Comment: Ideally JS and CSS should be reachable but yes, it can be the problem, and in this case may be the archive filesystem would work, which is supported by default, I will try to make a small demo to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Rolf of Saxony's answer worked for me but I can add that the `Marker` can be fixed by using the `parse_html` option:

```
folium.Marker([-43.5321,172.6362], popup='Marker1', parse_html=True).add_to(fmap)
```

That will show the map and marker in the `wx.html2.WebView`.